# How to distribute files in a Python sdist that are not VCS tracked?

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, sdist

I would like to find the proper way to include files in a python sdist that are not tracked by git.

## Context

The `.mo` files from my project are not tracked by `git` (like some other `.txt` files that need to be created at install time).

I have written a small function in `setup.py` to create them at install time, that I call in `setup()`:

```
setup(
    .
    .
    .
    data_files=create_extra_files(),
    include_package_data=True,
    .
    .
    .
)
```

Note that they should belong to `data_dir` because [the documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files):

> The data_files option can be used to specify additional files needed
>   by the module distribution: configuration files, **message catalogs**,
>   data files, anything which doesn’t fit in the previous categories.

So, this works well with `python3 setup.py install` (and `bdist` too). The `.mo` files are generated and stored at the right place.

But if I want it to work with `sdist`, then I must include them in `MANIFEST.in` (e.g. `recursive-include mathmaker *.mo`). [Documentation says indeed](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files):

> Changed in version 3.1:  All the files that match data_files will be added to the MANIFEST file
>   **if no template is provided**. See [Specifying the files to distribute](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest).

(The link doesn't help much).

I am reluctant to include `*.mo` files in `MANIFEST.in` as they are not tracked by git. And [check-manifest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/check-manifest) doesn't like this kind of situation, it complains about the fact that `lists of files in version control and sdist do not match!`

So, is there a way to fix this ugly situation?

## Steps to reproduce the situation

### Environment and project

To avoid polluting your environment, create and activate a dedicated virtual environment (python3.4+) in the directory of your choice:

```
$ pyvenv-3.4 v0
$ source v0/bin/activate
(v0) $
```

Reproduce following tree in a `project0` directory:

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
├── setup.py
└── project0
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── data
        └── dummy_versioned.po
```

Where `README.rst`, `__init__.py` and `dummy_versioned.po` are empty.

Content of the other files:

- `.gitignore`:

  ```
  build/
  dist/
  *.egg-info
  project0/data/*.txt
  *~
  ```
- `MANIFEST.in`:

  ```
  recursive-include project0 *.po
  recursive-include project0 *.txt
  ```
- `main.py`:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


  def entry_point():
      with open('project0/data/a_file.txt', mode='rt') as f:
          print(f.read())
  ```
- `setup.py`:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

  import platform
  from setuptools import setup, find_packages


  def create_files():
      txt_file_path = 'project0/data/a_file.txt'
      with open(txt_file_path, mode='w+') as f:
          f.write("Some dummy platform information: " + platform.platform())
      return [('project0/data', [txt_file_path])]


  setup(
      name='project0',
      version='0.0.1',
      author='J. Doe',
      author_email='j.doe@someprovider.com',
      url='http://myproject.url',
      packages=find_packages(),
      data_files=create_files(),
      include_package_data=True,
      entry_points={
          'console_scripts': ['myscript0 = project0.main:entry_point'],
      }
  )
  ```

Start a local `git` repo:

```
(v0) $ git init
(v0) $ git add .
```

Install `check-manifest`:

```
(v0) $ pip3 install check-manifest
```

### Install and test

`install` works:

```
(v0) $ python3 setup.py install
.
.
.
copying project0/data/a_file.txt -> build/lib/project0/data
.
.
.
Finished processing dependencies for project0==0.0.1
(v0) $ myscript0 
Some dummy platform information: Linux-3.16.0-29-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
```

If you `rm project0/data/a_file.txt`, then `myscript0` doesn't work anymore, but reinstall it and it works again, as expected.

Building the sdist also includes `a_file.txt`:

```
(v0) $ python3 setup.py sdist
.
.
.
hard linking project0/data/a_file.txt -> project0-0.0.1/project0/data
.
.
.
```

Note that to have this file included in the sdist, it looks necessary (as explained in the "context" part below) to have `recursive-include project0 *.txt` in `MANIFEST.in`. Would you remove this line, `python3 setup.py sdist` woudln't mention `a_file.txt` any more (do not forget to remove any previous `build/` or `dist/` directories to observe this).

### Conclusion

So, everything works as it is, but there is this discrepancy: `a_file.txt` is not tracked by `git`, but is included in `MANIFEST.in`.

`check-manifest` tells clearly:

```
lists of files in version control and sdist do not match!
missing from VCS:
  project0/data/a_file.txt
```

So, is there a proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: OK, then I can remove it. But on Stack Overflow, won't I be said that I am talking about a case that has no problem? Woudln't I better edit this question on CodeReview to add a MCVE in it? (I think it's possible)

Comment: If you edit in actual code that works, we can review it.

Comment: @zezollo We deal in real code, not an MCVE. Perhaps this question is more appropriate on Programmers SE, but please [follow the tour](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) before posting.

Comment: Can you generate `MANIFEST.in` on the _pre-commit_ hook?(I haven't used _setup.py_ before but I think this may solve the problem)

Comment: @syb0rg I have added working code. It's a bit long to describe, but everything is here. Tell me if it's too long or still not on topic.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Do you mean an MCVE can also not be real code?

Comment: @zezollo ["we ask for your actual, real code and not a MCVE/boiled-down/'simplified version' of the code to be reviewed"](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6256/10582)

Comment: @BCdotWEB OK, well, I understand. Now, my question is exclusively about the code I have posted in the EDIT. No one can consider there's any *real code behind* it (except I've anonymized the posted part). Is there still a problem?

Comment: It's not clear what code you are asking us to review — `setup.py`? Also, judging from your Conclusion section, the process doesn't work as intended, so it would still be off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @200_success The process itself does work, there's no bug (that's why I didn't think it would fit on Stack Overflow). There may be something to change in `setup.py` or `MANIFEST.in` or maybe add a missing file (plus a missing configuration?), this is what I don't know. I'd liked to know what is usually done in such a case (so belongs to "Does this code follow common best practices?"). Or do you mean there should be an algorithm and my question is more about configuration? Should I better delete it and re-ask on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Is your question about how to suppress the "lists of files in version control and sdist do not match!" warning?

Comment: @200_success Not far from that, but not exactly: maybe there is indeed a way to change the code that would result in suppressing this warning (while not including another bad practice). In this case, yes (do you mean, then it can be considered like a bug, or kind of?). But maybe this warning cannot be avoided: it's not good practice but as of today this situation cannot be handled better, so people follow this practice for lack of anything better OR maybe it's just okay this way and `check-manifest` outputs a warning it shouldn't. Sorry for all that and thanks for your replies!

Comment: Since you are [asking a specific question rather than soliciting open-ended feedback](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users), this is a question for Stack Overflow rather than Code Review. "How do I suppress this warning?", "Is this a bug?", or "Is there a proper way to …?" are all specific questions that would be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @200_success alright, many thanks for all this! And sorry to have caused all these discussions!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I get your problem **you would like to add files to be distributed with the git repository but you don't want to keep track of their changes.**

This can be done by this four simple steps:

**Step 0:**
First ensure you the content inside the `path/a_file.txt` file matches with the content you want to distribute. As far as I know it can't be empty, so if you simply want this file to exist add a newline/space character to it.

**Step 1:**
Add the file(s) to git using `git add path/a_file.txt`

**Step 2:**
Commit the files (`git commit path/a_file.txt`)

**Step 3:**
Update git's index and tell git it should ignore further
changes on the files
`git update-index --assume-unchanged path/a_file.txt`

If you ever want to do some changes to this file which should again be tracked, you can simply use the `--no-assume-unchanged` flag to set it
active in git's index and then commit the changes.

**Note** that the creation of a `.gitignore` file which tells git to ignore the files (on all machines that clone the repository) and using `git add --force path/a_file.txt` won't work since git will (`force`) add it to the index and also *keep track of the changes*.